# Track PWA events in Google AMP + PWA ( PWAMP)

Tags: google-analytics, progressive-web-apps, amp-html, amp-analytics

How do you track if a AMP page with PWA is added to Home Screen via Google Analytics ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not currently possible in AMP, but [there's an open feature request on GitHub](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/7508).